# Dynamically add and remove inputs and update nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

How to add new input fields dynamically to object in nested array in react js when user clicks on plus sign? dynamically add and remove inputs

I want to add and delete propositionTimes dynamically in the handlepropositionTimeAddClick and handlepropositionTimeRemoveClick methods I shared below. How can I do that? And I want to do the same with propositionResponseTimes and analyzers.

```
const [issue, setIssue] = useState({
    
    firstResponseDuration: "",
    firstResponseOvertime: "",
    solutionDuration: "",
    solutionOvertime: "",
    propositionTimes: [{
     
      propositionTime: ""
    }],
    propositionResponseTimes: [{  propositionResponseTime: "" }],
    analyzers: [{  analyzerName: "", analyzerHuaweiId: "" }],
  });

  const { firstResponseDuration, firstResponseOvertime,solutionDuration, solutionOvertime, propositionTimes, propositionResponseTimes, analyzers } = issue;
.
.
.

 // handle click event of the Remove button
  const handlepropositionTimeRemoveClick = index => {
  
  };

  // handle click event of the Add button
  const handlepropositionTimeAddClick = (i) => {
   
  };
.
.
.
   {
            issue.propositionTimes.map((item, i) => {
              return (
                <div key={i} className="form-group" >
                  <label>
                    Proposition Time
                  </label>
                  <TextField
                    type="datetime-local"
                    placeholder="Enter propositionTime"
                    name="propositionTime"
                    format="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
                    value={item.propositionTime}
                    onChange={e => onInputPropositionTimes(e, i)}
                  />

                  <div>
                    {issue.propositionTimes.length !== 1 && <button
                      className="mr10"
                      onClick={() => handlepropositionTimeRemoveClick(i)}>Remove</button>}
                    {issue.propositionTimes.length - 1 === i && <button onClick={handlepropositionTimeAddClick(i)}>Add</button>}
                  </div>


                </div>
              )
            })
          }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  // handle click event of the Remove button
  const handlepropositionTimeRemoveClick = index => {
    const issueObj = {...issue};
    const filteredIssue = issue.propositionTimes.filter((item, ind) => ind !== index);
    issueObj.propositionTimes = filteredIssue;
    setIssue(issueObj);
  };

  // handle click event of the Add button
  const handlepropositionTimeAddClick = (i) => {
    const issueObj = {...issue};    
    const newObj = {
      propositionTime: ""   // Code to add new propositionTime
    }
    issueObj.propositionTimes.push(newObj)
    setIssue(issueObj);
  };
```

Also in your `handlepropositionTimeAddClick` function, don't call it directly. Just pass the reference

```
{issue.propositionTimes.length - 1 === i && <button onClick={() => handlepropositionTimeAddClick(i)}>Add</button>}
```

Comment: I tried the solution you wrote but it gave an error because the database was updated and there is no id in these rows.                                                                                                                                ```  solutionOvertime: "",
    propositionTimes: [{
      propositionTime: ""
    }],
    propositionResponseTimes: [{ propositionResponseTime: "" }],
    analyzers: [{ analyzerName: "", analyzerHuaweiId: "" }],```

Comment: Alright!! I've updated the answer. Plz check if it works

Comment: Whats the issue?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined                                                                           334 | <div className="form-group">
      | ^  335 |   <label>
  336 |     Solution Overtime
  337 |   </label>

Comment: Ohh!! My bad. It should be `setIssue(issueObj);` not `setIssue(newObj);` Updated answer. plz check

Comment: Updated the answer. Try now.

Comment: handlepropositionTimeAddClick  for that i updated it like this setIssue(issueObj);.                                   now it says that as an error "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Comment: For me it works correctly. Look at this snippet. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hw2ajz?file=src/App.js

Comment: the error `Error: Too many re-renders.` was caused bcz you have directly called `handlepropositionTimeAddClick(i)` but instead u just have to pass the reference of it like i've mentioned in the answer

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying, I'll write if there is any update.

Comment: When I click the add button, I want it to create an input field on a new line, but when I click the button, it doesn't work.

Comment: what doesn't work? `Creating input field?` or `New Line?`

Comment: It does not create new input field

Comment: There's something wrong with the code apart from the code u have pasted in question. Bcz when i write above code it works for me perfectly. See this https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-hamilton-lzi4n?file=/src/App.js